What is the JSON code for just showing profile picture (not the name) in a SharePoint list view?
I have a SharePoint list with a Person column and the list has 3 views. For the 3rd view I want only the picture shown and not the name of the person.
How can I do that?

You can show only user image and hide user name using SharePoint JSON column formatting.
However, when you apply JSON column formatting to any column, it will change the display of column from All list views, not only specific SharePoint list view (if this is what you want - For the 3rd view I want only the picture shown and not the name of the person).
You can find the related JSON samples in PnP List formatting samples Github repository:

Display a Person's Profile Picture in a Circle - single selection person or group column


Multi-Person Facepile - multiple selections person or group column




If you want to show user image and hide user name for only one list view and keep both image and name of users for all other list views, you will have to format the 3rd list view from scratch and build custom list view using JSON. Note, it will remove all SharePoint OOTB functionalities (filtering/sorting/context menu, etc.).
Related links:

Change column name in view using json view formatting
SharePoint Modern List - Change fill color of column headers
Custom Header & List view - view formatting sample


There is sample code for a round person image in Github.
https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/person-roundimage-format
You can change the JSON settings to another shape if needed.

This sample applies styles to a parent div element and a child img
element to show a person's profile picture in a circle.
The size can be easily adjusted by changing the default value of 32px
for both the width and height style attributes on the parent div.
You can also adjust the border-radius value of the parent div to
change it from a full circle (50%) to a rounded rectangle (< 50%). To
get larger profile pictures you can change the size=S portion of the
URL to use either size=M or size=L. See the table below for details on
image size.
For best results, images should be square (S & M user profile pictures
always are).



If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.
